# Kotlin Delegated Property name still visible after obfuscation

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I notied that Kotlin Delegated Property names still visible in the obfuscated bytecode.

Example source code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val testProperty by lazy { "this is testProperty value" }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        testMethod()
        Log.d("MainActivity", "testProperty: $testProperty")
    }

    fun testMethod() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "this is testMethod")
    }
}
```

I'm build apk with minification enabled and then use APK Analyzing feature from Android Studio to browse bytecode:

```
.method private final l()V
    .registers 3

    const-string v0, "MainActivity"

    const-string v1, "this is testMethod"

    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Landroid/util/Log;->d(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I

    return-void
.end method
```

...

```
invoke-static {v2}, La/a/b/k;->a(Ljava/lang/Class;)La/b/b;

    move-result-object v2

    const-string v3, "testProperty"

    const-string v4, "getTestProperty()Ljava/lang/String;"

    invoke-direct {v1, v2, v3, v4}, La/a/b/j;-><init>(La/b/c;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    invoke-static {v1}, La/a/b/k;->a(La/a/b/i;)La/b/e;
```

In the fragments above you could see that `testMethod` obfuscated well, but `testProperty` is still visible.

How could I remove this info from bytecode to improve obfuscation and make it more difficult to reverse engineer?

Answer (score 1):

The name of a delegated property is part of its API: the property delegate receives the name as parameter and can use it as, for example, the name of a database column or a key in a persistence format. Therefore, it can't simply be removed from bytecode; it has as much meaning there as any other string literal (like the "this is testProperty value" string).

If you're genuinely concerned that knowing the name of a specific property makes an essential difference for someone trying to reverse-engineer your application, don't use delegated properties in such code. However, I'm pretty sure that such concerns are unfounded in 95% of cases.

Comment: I know, I could refuse to use delegated properties (and I'm actually don't use them in critical places), but I want to use them and that's why I'm asking. 
Yes, propery metadata is required in some cases but in the most common cases (like lazy initialization) we don't need it.

Comment: At this time the Kotlin compiler has no possibility to detect whether a property delegate makes use of the property name. The API is the same for all delegates.

Comment: thanks for replies. As I see in the byte code, `getTestProperty()` method that was generated for `testPropery` is renamed (obfuscated), but string literal is unchanged. Ideally would be not to remove names but update them accordingly with related methods. In cases when names should be preserved, we could use existing proguard options.

Comment: Once again: The property names can be used in external data. Suppose you have an Android app that uploads JSON to the server, and uses delegated properties to build the JSON. Would it indeed be ideal if the debug build of your app submitted JSON data where a key is called "userName", and the release build called the same key "xz"?

Comment: And of course ProGuard has no knowledge of Kotlin delegated properties and their semantics. To it, the delegated property name looks exactly like any other string literal.